# Error404:The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to springboot ,was trying to connect a controller to the webpage using tomcat 9.0.53. Although the connection to the server is successful,however I am not able to display view on the server and it gives me this error.  Error 404:The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Here is my controller class:

```
package com.emusicstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class homeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Dispatcher_Servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Please help me figure out the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you check your tomcat logs it generally gives the idea about the problem,by the looks of it now Change the name from '**Dispatcher_Servlet.xml**' to '**dispatcher-servlet.xml**' also check dispatcher-servlet.xml is placed in WEB-INF Folder After that

If your using maven then :

1)Maven Clean

2)Maven Install

3)Run the Project Again

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> //make sure the servlet name is correct i.e Case sensitive
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the leads.But I had kept it dispatcher-servlet only, there was a mistake on my part while posting the question here.The file name is dispatcher-servlet.xml and I have checked the url-pattern it matches.I am working on spring .But the issue isn't resolved yet